# Why does dnf uninstall python-pip want to uninstall Fedora?

Tags: fedora, python, package-management, pip

Having trouble installing packages with pip (wow. so unexpect. much surprise) and upon trying to toss it entirely and start over (no, dnf reinstall was not sufficient) I found that dnf seemed to think that everything and the kitchen sink could also be tossed:

```
> sudo dnf remove python-pip
Dependencies resolved.
========================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Arch                     Version                                          Repository                        Size
========================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 GitPython                                             noarch                   1.0.1-2.fc23                                     @@commandline                    2.1 M
 PyPAM                                                 x86_64                   0.5.0-22.fc23                                    @@commandline                     51 k
 PyQt4                                                 x86_64                   4.11.4-2.fc23                                    @fedora                           16 M
 VirtualBox-4.3                                        x86_64                   4.3.34_104062_fedora22-1                         @virtualbox                      141 M
 abrt-addon-python                                     x86_64                   2.7.1-1.fc23                                     @updates                          19 k
 abrt-python                                           x86_64                   2.7.1-1.fc23                                     @updates                          63 k
 anaconda                                              x86_64                   23.19.10-1.fc23                                  @@commandline                      0  
 anaconda-core                                         x86_64                   23.19.10-1.fc23                                  @@commandline                    7.8 M
 anaconda-gui                                          x86_64                   23.19.10-1.fc23                                  @@commandline                    1.3 M
 anaconda-tui                                          x86_64                   23.19.10-1.fc23                                  @@commandline                    380 k
 anaconda-yum-plugins                                  noarch                   1:1.0-10.fc20                                    @System                           21 k
 audit-libs-python                                     x86_64                   2.4.5-1.fc23                                     @updates                         470 k
 authconfig-gtk                                        x86_64                   6.2.10-10.fc23                                   @@commandline                    258 k
 bcache-tools                                          x86_64                   1.0.8-4.fc23                                     @@commandline                     74 k
 blivet-data                                           noarch                   1:1.12.8-1.fc23                                  @@commandline                    427 k
 blueman                                               x86_64                   2.1-0.3.git7a2e20e.fc23                          @@commandline                    4.8 M
 bodhi-client                                          noarch                   0.9.12.2-3.fc23                                  @@commandline                     27 k
 cairo-devel                                           x86_64                   1.14.2-2.fc23                                    @@commandline                    2.6 M
 cinnamon                                              x86_64                   2.8.6-1.fc23                                     @updates                         7.9 M
 cinnamon-control-center                               x86_64                   2.8.0-2.fc23                                     @updates                         6.6 M
 cinnamon-desktop                                      x86_64                   2.8.0-2.fc23                                     @updates                         754 k
 cinnamon-screensaver                                  x86_64                   2.8.0-2.fc23                                     @updates                         320 k
 cinnamon-session                                      x86_64                   2.8.2-2.fc23                                     @updates                         995 k
 cinnamon-settings-daemon                              x86_64                   2.8.1-2.fc23                                     @updates                         5.8 M
 cmake                                                 x86_64                   3.3.2-1.fc23                                     @fedora                           22 M
 compat-libvpx1                                        x86_64                   1.3.0-3.fc23                                     @@commandline                    1.3 M
 cryptsetup-python                                     x86_64                   1.6.8-2.fc23                                     @@commandline                     57 k
 dbus-python                                           x86_64                   1.2.0-12.fc23                                    @updates                         479 k
 eclipse-collabnet-merge                               noarch                   4.0.2-2.fc23                                     @@commandline                    514 k
 eclipse-fedorapackager                                noarch                   0.5.0-5.fc23                                     @@commandline                    2.9 M
 eclipse-pydev                                         x86_64                   1:4.4.0-3.fc23                                   @updates                         9.9 M
 eclipse-subclipse                                     noarch                   1.10.10-1.fc23                                   @updates                         5.1 M
 fedora-cert                                           noarch                   0.5.10.5-2.fc23                                  @@commandline                     57 k
 fedora-packager                                       noarch                   0.5.10.5-2.fc23                                  @@commandline                     80 k
 fedpkg                                                noarch                   1.20-2.fc23                                      @@commandline                     72 k
 glib2-devel                                           x86_64                   2.46.2-1.fc23                                    @updates                         2.5 M
 glibmm24-devel                                        x86_64                   2.46.2-1.fc23                                    @updates                         3.1 M
 gnome-python2                                         x86_64                   2.28.1-16.fc23                                   @@commandline                    155 k
 gnome-python2-bonobo                                  x86_64                   2.28.1-16.fc23                                   @@commandline                    375 k
 gnome-python2-canvas                                  x86_64                   2.28.1-16.fc23                                   @@commandline                     79 k
 gnome-python2-gconf                                   x86_64                   2.28.1-16.fc23                                   @@commandline                    142 k
 gnome-python2-gnome                                   x86_64                   2.28.1-16.fc23                                   @@commandline                    369 k
 gnome-python2-gnomevfs                                x86_64                   2.28.1-16.fc23                                   @@commandline                    344 k
 google-chrome-stable                                  x86_64                   47.0.2526.106-1                                  @google-chrome                   171 M
 imsettings-cinnamon                                   x86_64                   1.6.8-6.fc23                                     @@commandline                    505 k
 initial-setup                                         x86_64                   0.3.37-1.fc23                                    @@commandline                    134 k
 js-jquery                                             noarch                   2.1.3-2.fc23                                     @@commandline                    478 k
 jsoncpp                                               x86_64                   0.6.0-0.18.rc2.fc23                              @fedora                          144 k
 jython                                                noarch                   2.7-2.fc23                                       @@commandline                     26 M
 kde-filesystem                                        x86_64                   4-52.fc23                                        @fedora                          3.9 k
 koji                                                  noarch                   1.10.1-1.fc23                                    @updates                         958 k
 krb5-workstation                                      x86_64                   1.14-4.fc23                                      @updates                         2.4 M
 langtable-python                                      noarch                   0.0.34-1.fc23                                    @@commandline                    133 k
 libblockdev                                           x86_64                   1.3-4.fc23                                       @updates                         167 k
 libblockdev-kbd                                       x86_64                   1.3-4.fc23                                       @updates                          27 k
 libblockdev-plugins-all                               x86_64                   1.3-4.fc23                                       @updates                           0  
 libqzeitgeist                                         x86_64                   0.8.0-14.fc23                                    @fedora                          234 k
 libreport-python                                      x86_64                   2.6.3-1.fc23                                     @@commandline                    116 k
 libselinux-python                                     x86_64                   2.4-4.fc23                                       @@commandline                    1.2 M
 libsemanage-python                                    x86_64                   2.4-4.fc23                                       @@commandline                    379 k
 libsigc++20-devel                                     x86_64                   2.6.2-1.fc23                                     @updates                         1.0 M
 libuser-python                                        x86_64                   0.62-1.fc23                                      @@commandline                     66 k
 libxml++-devel                                        x86_64                   2.40.1-1.fc23                                    @updates                         132 k
 libxml2-devel                                         x86_64                   2.9.3-2.fc23                                     @updates                         8.9 M
 liveusb-creator                                       noarch                   3.14.2-2.fc23                                    @fedora                          834 k
 mintlocale                                            noarch                   1.1.6-0.6.gitfb4118d.fc23                        @@commandline                    300 k
 mock                                                  noarch                   1.2.14-1.fc23                                    @updates                         957 k
 mock-scm                                              noarch                   1.2.14-1.fc23                                    @updates                         7.0 k
 nemo                                                  x86_64                   2.8.5-1.fc23                                     @updates                         3.1 M
 nemo-extensions                                       x86_64                   2.8.5-1.fc23                                     @updates                         263 k
 nemo-fileroller                                       x86_64                   2.8.x-2.fc23                                     @updates                          37 k
 nemo-preview                                          x86_64                   2.8.x-2.fc23                                     @updates                         307 k
 newt-python                                           x86_64                   0.52.18-3.fc23                                   @@commandline                    118 k
 nmap                                                  x86_64                   2:7.00-1.fc23                                    @updates                          20 M
 notify-python                                         x86_64                   0.1.1-29.fc23                                    @@commandline                     73 k
 numpy                                                 x86_64                   1:1.9.2-2.fc23                                   @@commandline                     14 M
 numpy-f2py                                            x86_64                   1:1.9.2-2.fc23                                   @@commandline                    1.0 M
 opencv-python                                         x86_64                   2.4.12.3-1.fc23                                  @updates                         1.3 M
 packagedb-cli                                         noarch                   2.10-2.fc23                                      @updates                         205 k
 phonon                                                x86_64                   4.8.3-7.fc23                                     @fedora                          635 k
 phonon-backend-gstreamer                              x86_64                   2:4.8.2-5.fc23                                   @fedora                          385 k
 policycoreutils-devel                                 x86_64                   2.4-18.fc23                                      @updates                         669 k
 policycoreutils-gui                                   x86_64                   2.4-18.fc23                                      @updates                         3.0 M
 policycoreutils-python                                x86_64                   2.4-18.fc23                                      @updates                         1.1 M
 pyOpenSSL                                             noarch                   0.15.1-1.fc23                                    @@commandline                    1.0 M
 pyatspi                                               noarch                   2.18.0-1.fc23                                    @@commandline                    402 k
 pycairo                                               x86_64                   1.10.0-2.fc23                                    @@commandline                    1.0 M
 pycairo-devel                                         x86_64                   1.10.0-2.fc23                                    @@commandline                    7.4 k
 pyexiv2                                               x86_64                   0.3.2-19.fc23                                    @@commandline                    1.1 M
 pygobject2                                            x86_64                   2.28.6-14.fc23                                   @@commandline                    874 k
 pygpgme                                               x86_64                   0.3-13.fc23                                      @@commandline                    232 k
 pygtk2                                                x86_64                   2.24.0-12.fc23                                   @@commandline                    3.9 M
 pygtk2-libglade                                       x86_64                   2.24.0-12.fc23                                   @@commandline                     24 k
 pyliblzma                                             x86_64                   0.5.3-14.fc23                                    @@commandline                    192 k
 pylint                                                noarch                   1.4.3-3.fc23                                     @@commandline                    1.4 M
 pyorbit                                               x86_64                   2.24.0-18.fc23                                   @@commandline                    125 k
 pyparsing                                             noarch                   2.0.3-2.fc23                                     @@commandline                    385 k
 pyparted                                              x86_64                   1:3.10.7-1.fc23                                  @@commandline                    374 k
 pyrpkg                                                noarch                   1.36-1.fc23                                      @@commandline                    405 k
 python                                                x86_64                   2.7.10-8.fc23                                    @@commandline                     78 k
 .
 .
 .
 A bunch of python
 .
 .
 .
 pytz                                                  noarch                   2015.4-1.fc23                                    @@commandline                    231 k
 pyxattr                                               x86_64                   0.5.3-5.fc23                                     @@commandline                     62 k
 pyxdg                                                 noarch                   0.25-6.fc23                                      @@commandline                    326 k
 redhat-lsb                                            x86_64                   4.1-30.fc23                                      @@commandline                      0  
 redhat-lsb-languages                                  x86_64                   4.1-30.fc23                                      @@commandline                    814  
 rpm-python                                            x86_64                   4.13.0-0.rc1.7.fc23                              @updates                         186 k
 samba-common-tools                                    x86_64                   2:4.3.3-0.fc23                                   @updates                         1.1 M
 samba-libs                                            x86_64                   2:4.3.3-0.fc23                                   @updates                         718 k
 scipy                                                 x86_64                   0.14.1-1.fc22                                    @System                           38 M
 selinux-policy-devel                                  noarch                   3.13.1-158.fc23                                  @updates                          22 M
 sip                                                   x86_64                   4.17-1.fc23                                      @updates                         393 k
 subversion                                            x86_64                   1.9.3-1.fc23                                     @updates                         5.4 M
 subversion-javahl                                     x86_64                   1.9.3-1.fc23                                     @updates                         1.0 M
 syslinux                                              x86_64                   6.03-6.fc23                                      @fedora                          1.0 M
 syslinux-extlinux                                     x86_64                   6.03-6.fc23                                      @fedora                          205 k
 syslinux-extlinux-nonlinux                            noarch                   6.03-6.fc23                                      @fedora                          970 k
 syslinux-nonlinux                                     noarch                   6.03-6.fc23                                      @fedora                          1.7 M
 system-config-date                                    noarch                   1.10.9-1.fc23                                    @@commandline                    2.0 M
 system-config-keyboard                                noarch                   1.4.0-8.fc23                                     @@commandline                     40 k
 system-config-keyboard-base                           noarch                   1.4.0-8.fc23                                     @@commandline                    469 k
 system-config-language                                noarch                   3.3.0-1.fc23                                     @@commandline                    428 k
 system-config-users                                   noarch                   1.3.8-1.fc23                                     @@commandline                    1.8 M
 tkinter                                               x86_64                   2.7.10-8.fc23                                    @@commandline                    1.6 M
 units                                                 x86_64                   2.11-5.fc23                                      @@commandline                    498 k
 variety                                               noarch                   0.5.0-1.fc20                                     @System                          2.4 M
 web-assets-filesystem                                 noarch                   5-3.fc23                                         @@commandline                      0  
 yum                                                   noarch                   3.4.3-507.fc23                                   @@commandline                    5.6 M
 yum-langpacks                                         noarch                   0.4.5-2.fc23                                     @@commandline                     66 k
 yum-metadata-parser                                   x86_64                   1.1.4-15.fc23                                    @@commandline                     74 k
 yum-utils                                             noarch                   1.1.31-508.fc23                                  @@commandline                    334 k
 yumex                                                 noarch                   3.0.17-2.fc23                                    @@commandline                    1.6 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================
Remove  244 Packages

Installed size: 759 M
```

Now I'm no expert in exactly what is required for my Fedora 23 installation to run, but I'm pretty sure that annaconda, cinnamon, and syslinux are moderately important to my user experience.

Two questions:
 1. Why is this happening? 
 2. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dnf, but you may want to try adding the `-v` (`--verbose`) option for more details. That might tell you why it wants to remove so much.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt tell me anything extra.
It only listed the package's full name and noted that it would be erased.

However, it does note them as "unneeded leftover dependencies". Maybe theres a way to leave those "unneeded leftover dependencies", since, you know, they arent.

Comment: Hm... The only setting related to dnf remove seems to be clean_requirements_on_remove setting in the /etc/dnf/dnf.conf file. But changing it to false (it's true by default) didn't change anything when actually removing the package...

Comment: I saw something similar to this once before, where a poorly packaged application had hundreds of bundled C libraries that weren't filtered.  That combined with dnf's default `clean_requirements_on_remove` behavior caused a similar massive removal attempt any time I tried to erase a package.  You might try to confirm if this is the case by running `dnf autoremove` and see if you get a similarly long output.  If you do, the problem isn't python-pip, and you'll have to narrow down what package is providing too many things.

Comment: Just so no-one spends too much time trying to make this work and asking me questions, I wiped my install after some (hopefully unrelated) issues I was having with Fedora.
CentOS 7 seems a tad bit more stable.

Comment: anaconda is the Fedora installer, it's not really "important to your user experience." The other two are.